# using https in php on apache and windows platform

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, https

how to use apache in https mode
in other words what should i do to make a certain page uses https instead of http

Answer (score 1):

I will point you to two pages.

**Apache + SSl Setup** - 
http://tud.at/programm/apache-ssl-win32-howto.php3

**Expanded self-signed SSL Certificate Details** - http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html

I will assume this is for personal/dev use, since I hope you are not planning on setting up a production server and asking  this question. These pages will tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the apache server listen on port 80 and 443, get certificates for you server, you can generate certs with openssl on windows also, configure your httpd.conf ssl settings to match your certs path and finally use mod_rewrite to force ssl on specific directories.